# r: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: object '72L' not found

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run frame_calendar for my univariate time series data in r. When I try to compute the calendar layout for the data frame, I am getting the following error.

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: object '72L' not found.

From similar threads, I see the evaluation error: object ' ' not found is usually for an object the users have input in the code. However, in my case, I am not referring to any '72L' in my code. And it is not in my data set as well. Can you please help me figure out how to fix this error? Any help is much appreciated.

Here is a part of my data.

```
Date_Time   Time    Date    Year    Month   Mdate   Day Hours_Time  Hourly_Counts
1/1/2015 0:00   0:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    1   72
1/1/2015 1:00   1:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    2   48
1/1/2015 2:00   2:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    3   53
1/1/2015 3:00   3:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    4   84
1/1/2015 4:00   4:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    5   68
```

Here's my code.

```
newdata <- read.csv("D:/NEWDATA.csv")
attach(newdata)
View(newdata)

newdata[,3] <- as.Date(Date, origin = "1/1/2000")
attach(newdata)
View(newdata)


library(dplyr)
# compute the calendar layout for the data frame
calendar_df <- newdata %>%
  filter(Year == 2015) %>%
  frame_calendar(x = Time, y = Hourly_Counts, date = Date)
```

Comment: `frame_calendar` is from `suggrants`?  And two side notes: 1) don't `attach()` your data frame, especially if you're going to use tidyverse functions (which use nonstandard evaluation). 2) you do have `72L` in your data. It's the integer `72`, which is the first value in `newdata$Hourly_Counts`

Comment: Yes, then if you use base methods to mutate, you'll have to wrap it in `with()` or extract them explicitly (e.g., `newdata$Date`)

Comment: @DanHall yes, `frame_calendar` is from `suggrants` package. if i don't `attach()` data frame the first time after reading the data, as you suggested, then i get the error: 
> Error in as.Date(Date, origin = "1/1/2000") : object 'Date' not found.
However, if I `attach()` the first time and omit the 2nd `attach()` I still get the 
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: object '72L' not found.
Also, I can see your point in the integer `72`, i just don't understand why the calendar layout is searching for a specific data value. 
I apologize if this is too basic question.

Comment: @DanHall here is an edited version of my code. I have tried `tibble()` as an alternative to convert `Date` to a `Date Class`. 

`newpm10 <- read.csv("D:/NEWDATA.csv")
View(newdata)

newdata <- as_tibble(newdata)

newdate <- as.Date(Date, origin = "1/1/2000")
View(newdate)
newdata <- mutate(newdata, Date = newdate)
View(newdata)


library(dplyr)
# compute the calendar layout for the data frame
calendar_df <- newdata %>%
  filter(Year == 2015) %>%
  frame_calendar(x = Time, y = Hourly_Counts, date = Date)`

however it is still giving the same error. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The main source of your problem is that you used `attach`, which masked `Hourly_Counts` in the call to `frame_calendar`. See the answer below. To run it, make sure you start with a clean environment. You've run `attach()` multiple times, which means you're going to have to `detach` for each of those times.

Comment: run `detach(new_data)` until you get `Error in detach(new_data) : invalid 'name' argument`. And seriously, avoid `detach` from here on out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that when you `attach()` your data frame first you mask a number of objects that you need. Generally, don't use `attach`.  If you want to work with an attached data set, use it inside a call to `with`,  and certainly don't combine this with `dplyr` or other `tidyverse` functions.

With a clean environment (no data or namespaces attached), use `dplyr` methods throughout, like this. Other than not attaching, notice the two other changes to your code. (1) use `mutate` to set the `Date` column within the `dplyr` pipe. (2) `x = Hours_Time`, rather than `Time`. If you've previously run `attach(new_data)`,  do `detach(new_data)` first, UNTIL you have a clean environment. **If you've run it multiple times, you're going to have to `detach` multiple times.**

```
library(dplyr)
library(sugrrants)
new_data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, origin = "1/1/2000")) %>%
  frame_calendar(x = Hours_Time, y = Hourly_Counts, date = Date)
#       Date_Time    Time Year   Month Mdate      Day Hours_Time Hourly_Counts       Date
# 1 1/1/2015 0:00 0:00:00 2015 January     1 Thursday          1            72 2015-01-01
# 2 1/1/2015 1:00 1:00:00 2015 January     1 Thursday          2            48 2015-01-01
# 3 1/1/2015 2:00 2:00:00 2015 January     1 Thursday          3            53 2015-01-01
# 4 1/1/2015 3:00 3:00:00 2015 January     1 Thursday          4            84 2015-01-01
# 5 1/1/2015 4:00 4:00:00 2015 January     1 Thursday          5            68 2015-01-01
#   .Hours_Time .Hourly_Counts
# 1    1.454167      0.6833333
# 2    1.691667      0.0500000
# 3    1.929167      0.1819444
# 4    2.166667      1.0000000
# 5    2.404167      0.5777778
```

Data:

```
new_data <- read.table(text = "Date_Time   Time    Date    Year    Month   Mdate   Day Hours_Time  Hourly_Counts
'1/1/2015 0:00'   0:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    1   72
                       '1/1/2015 1:00'   1:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    2   48
                       '1/1/2015 2:00'   2:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    3   53
                       '1/1/2015 3:00'   3:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    4   84
                       '1/1/2015 4:00'   4:00:00 2015-01-01  2015    January 1   Thursday    5   68", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you for the advise. will keep this in mind. 
and your solution has finally solved the problem. i think the main problem apart from `attach()` was that I used `Time` as `x` value instead of `Hours_Time`, as I had previously run `detach()` several times, but got the same error. @DanHall